# How to create a feature collection with mean values of certain features and the location/shape of a different feature collection?

Tags: merge, qgis, google-earth-engine

I have two feature collections one containing point data with measurements and the other polygons marking the different clusters where several measurements were taken close together. In Google earth engine I am trying to create a new (point) feature collection (or edit the polygon features) which contain the average measured values for every seperate cluster.

I used the following code to join the two different feature collections (so that the polygons also contain the point data):

```
 var mean = ee.Filter.intersects({
    leftField: '.geo',
    rightField: '.geo'
  })

var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'Measurements',
})

var intersect = saveAllJoin.apply(Clusters, Measurements, mean)
```

However, since multiple measurements are taken within one cluster this results in a featurecollection that contains a list with the measurement points located within a specific cluster. Instead I am looking for the average measured values as a property of the polygons. What is the way to do this in Google earth engine (or possibly in QGIS)?

I have tried using `ee.FeatureCollection.map` in order to calculate the mean value at every individual polygon:

```
var clust = ee.FeatureCollection(Clusters).map(function(feature) {
  var meanClay = Measurements.reduceColumns({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    selectors: ['Clay']
  })
  return feature.set('mean', meanClay)
})
```

Now if I print the variable "clust" I get a featurecollection with mean values for the (measured) attribute clay. However, every feature gets the same value (the mean of all the measured points instead of just those within a specific cluster).

For clarity: I got a shapefile with 78 measurement locations (points) which are loaded into my script as a featurecollection and contain the measured values. Besides this I also have a shapefile with polygons indicating 16 areas where a cluster of measurements were performed (so around 4-5 measurements in each cluster). Now I am trying to get the average of all the measurements (points) within each polygon (cluster) for every individual polygon.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the shape of your data, but have you looked into `ee.FeatureCollection.map()` to summarise the point locations contained in each polygon?

Comment: I have now tried something with `ee.FeatureCollection.map()`, however I am quite new to Google Earth Engine and am not getting the results i want. I have added some extra information in my original question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: In the mapped function, instead of `Measurements` you should use `feature.get` to extract the property you want to summarize.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `filterBounds()` on the point data. Here the filterBounds is used to filter the point data to only consist of the points within a specific cluster.

```
var clust = ee.FeatureCollection(Clusters).map(function(feature) {
  var meanClay = ee.FeatureCollection(Measurements.filterBounds(feature.geometry()))
    .reduceColumns({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      selectors: ['Clay']
    })
  return feature.set(meanClay)
})
```